# Why does focal length of a concave mirror $f=-R/2$?

Tags: optics, conventions, reflection, lenses

When both the distances $R$ and $f$ are measured from mirror only they shouldn't be of sm sign? When we take it negative in mirror formula that I understood... But why here I'm confused

Comment: Do you mean *convex* mirror? The focal length of a concave mirror is positive.

Comment: The sign of the focal length depends on the sign convention being used so the OP needs to state the sign convention being used and the orientation of the concave mirror with regard to the sign convention.